# Linq Max Value from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, linq, max

I have an ObservableCollection with two properties string and int. I would like to query and return the int with the Max value.

Data example:

Category, WorkOrderVersion

AAA 1

AAA 2

AAA 3

BBB 1

BBB 2

if Category == "BBB" I would want to return 2

This is kind of what I mean:

```
var maxWorkOrderVersion = WorkOrderDetailsObsCollection.Where(x=>x.Category == firstSelection.Category) return Max(WorkOrderVersion);`
```

Comment: use Select and GroupBy, then sort it or max

Comment: You mean something like `WorkOrderDetailsObsCollection.Where(x=>x.Category == firstSelection.Category).Max(x => x.WorkOrderVersion)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the largest `WorkOrderVersion` for the selected `Category`, then you can return it using [`Max`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjDgdCVtNDiAhWCq54KHaIIDqYQFjACegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.linq.enumerable.max&usg=AOvVaw0XloZjxIfqzQsTJiQm6qNw):

```
int maxWorkOrderVersion = WorkOrderDetailsObsCollection
    .Where(x => x.Category == firstSelection.Category)
    .Max(x => x.WorkOrderVersion);
```

Otherwise, if you want the whole object for the specified `Category` that has the largest `WorkOrderVersion`, then you can order your list by the property (after filtering for the `Category`), and select the [`FirstOrDefault`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi9s-aHtNDiAhVBgp4KHdo2ClUQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.linq.enumerable.firstordefault&usg=AOvVaw1xUK53-HS8c6ttr82pBxsF) one (the default value of `null` would be returned in the case where no items of the specified `Category` exist):

```
var maxWorkOrderVersion = WorkOrderDetailsObsCollection
    .Where(x => x.Category == firstSelection.Category)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.WorkOrderVersion)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want get notifications when WorkOrderDetailsObsCollection changes or Category property changes, you can use my [ObservableComputations](https://github.com/IgorBuchelnikov/ObservableComputations) library. Using that library you can code:

```C#
var maxWorkOrderVersion = WorkOrderDetailsObsCollection
    .Filtering(x=> x.Category == firstSelection.Category)
    .Selecting(x => x.WorkOrderVersion)
    .Maximazing();

// maxWorkOrderVersion.Value is what you need
```

maxWorkOrderVersion is [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8). Actual value is stored in Value property. Ensure that properties mentioned in the code above notify of changes through the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) interface.